# Modify initialized Owl Carousel 2 slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

Is there any way to get the data from the carousel object after the page has loaded?

I'm using a plugin that generates a carousel after pulling in posts from a different site, but it has no options for the carousel settings.

I see on the page this after load:

```
    function initializeOwl(count) {
        jQuery(".display-medium-owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            items: count,
            lazyLoad: true,
        });
    }
...
initializeOwl(3);
```

In the console I've tried things like this:

```
 $('#display-medium-owl-demo').data('owl.carousel').options.dots = false;
```

The results come back as `Cannot read property 'options' of undefined` which makes sense as the object seems to be empty.

How can access the owlCarousel object so that I can perhaps destroy, modify settings, then reinitialize?